# How to programmatically upload a container to Azure Container Registry

Tags: c#, azure, docker, azure-container-service, azure-container-registry

Azure has a .NET API that's [pretty comprehensive and extensively documented.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/overview/azure/?view=azure-dotnet)  There are ways to programmatically accomplish just about anything that you can do in Azure, including all sorts of Docker-related stuff for the Azure Container Service, but one thing I can't find is how to upload a Docker container to an Azure Container Registry on your account.  And of course the Azure Container Service is kind of useless without any containers to run.

There's plenty of material online about how to do this from a command line, but I can't find any way to do it from the API.  How would I go about pushing a container from within a program?

Answer (score 1):

This post is intended more like a comment that is readable than a solid answer. The task of pushing a container is more complicated than calling a single API. Your code must manage the steps to save the container image to a file, which is a tar archive, then extracting the manifest and layers from the archive and finally uploading those objects to the registry.

The Azure Container Registry implements the Docker Registry API. This means that you will have better results searching for Docker examples.

Note: I am not aware of a .NET API, only the REST API and that API is just the blob upload portion. The rest of the steps you will need to code.

The first step is to extract the manifest and layers from the container. Each item is uploaded individually. **docker save** and **tar** simplify this process.

The process to upload a container is a multi-step process. The first item to upload is the manifest, then upload each layer. Both Docker and Azure call the data "blobs".

This API starts the process:

[Blob - Start Upload](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/containerregistry/blob/start-upload)

Example Docker document which explains the process and the APIs:

[Docker: Pushing An Image](https://docs.docker.com/registry/spec/api/#pushing-an-image)

Comment: Hi there - this answer has been very helpful since I started my own project of programmatically uploading container images to ACR, as the documentation is quite sparse. I am having some issues, however, particularly on the part of the project that *finishes* the upload. It seems that while the first few upload calls (starting the upload, uploading chunks) succeed, the "finalize upload" call typically results in a non-descript 400 Bad Request response. Considering that this post is one of the only resources I've managed to find on this subject, I wonder if you might have any insight. Thanks.